# Strange behavior Passing and multidimensional array as input to JavaScript function changes the array actual values? Please

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, parameters

I have created a variable of type multidimensional array in JavaScript and I console it before sending to function but it displays wrong output at console, but if i remove the function all works great

```
function ROT(a, d) {
    return a ^ d;
}

function thetha_step(A) {

    const C = [];
    const D = []; 
    //C[x] part 
    for (let x=0; x<5; x++) {
         C[x] = A[x][0];
         for (let y=1; y<5; y++) {
            C[x] = C[x] ^ A[x][y];
         }
    }

    //D[x] part
    D[0] = C[4] ^ ROT(C[1], 1);
    for (let x=1; x<5; x++) {
       D[x] = C[x-1] ^ ROT(C[x+1], 1);
    }

    //A[x,y]
    for (let x=0; x<5; x++) {
         for (let y=0; y<5; y++) {
             A[x][y] = A[x][y] ^ D[x];
         }
    }

    return A;
}


var bin= [
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
];


console.log(bin);

console.log(thetha_step(bin));
```

```
# Outputs as #

(5) [Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5)]
0: (5) [2, 3, 3, 3, 2]
1: (5) [2, 3, 2, 2, 2]
2: (5) [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
3: (5) [2, 3, 2, 2, 2]
4: (5) [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

(5) [Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5)]
0: (5) [2, 3, 3, 3, 2]
1: (5) [2, 3, 2, 2, 2]
2: (5) [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
3: (5) [2, 3, 2, 2, 2]
4: (5) [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Im not understanding why its not displaying correct bin variable values, but when I remove the function then all displays correct. Please help me where Im going wrong.

Comment: maybe you witness an asynchron output of the console of chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Comment: You'll want to look at [weird array behaviour in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49838597/215552), and [Why does changing an Array in JavaScript affect copies of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6612385/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things combining here.

First, arrays are objects and are thus passed "by reference". When you modify `A` inside the function, you're actually modifying the same array that is in `bin`, not a copy of it.

Second, the browser console displays "live" objects - when the contents of an object change, the console display changes too.

If you want to capture the value of `bin` as it was when you outputted it, try doing this instead:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(bin));
```