# Console log shows 'undefined' for a specific value of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to store the values that correspond to Sundays and Saturdays for the current month in an array (`arr`) and display it in the console, the variable 'd' represents the number of days in the current month.

When I try to display a specific value like `console.log(arr[1])` it shows "undefined" in the console.

```
let arr = [];
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]);

const renderDay = () => {
  let td = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= d; i++) {
    if (
      days[i].toLocaleDateString("fr-FR", options).slice(0, 3) === "sam" ||
      days[i].toLocaleDateString("fr-FR", options).slice(0, 3) === "dim"
    ) {
      td.push(
        <td className="test" key={i}>
          {days[i].toLocaleDateString("fr-FR", options).slice(0, 3)}
        </td>
      );
      arr.push(i);
    } else
      td.push(
        <td key={i}>
          {days[i].toLocaleDateString("fr-FR", options).slice(0, 3)}
        </td>
      );
  }
  return td;
};
```

I wanted to check if the array is empty, so I display the whole array with `console.log(arr)`,the output looks fine, it shows an array with length: 8 `arr = {0: 6 , 1: 7 , 2: 13 , 3: 14 , 4: 20 , 5: 21 , 6: 27 , 7: 28}`, who represents the index of Saturdays and Sundays in the current month, but I can't access to every specific value by index.

How I can access to every specific value by its index (`arr[0]`,`arr[1]`,`arr[2]`....)?

Comment: First of all, it's undefined because you just defined it. `let arr = []; console.log(arr);` will always log `[]` without a fair amount of work and luck. Secondly, if `days` contains `Date` objects, it would be far easier to do `if ([0,6].includes(days[i].getDay()))` to find out if it's a weekend day that formatting the date twice. Finally, what's `arr2`? It's not shown in your code, so I'm not sure where it's coming from.

Comment: There many undefined variable on your code,
Fix them up.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes `days` contains `Date` objects, i tried something like this `if(days[i].getDay()%6==0)` and it works fine ,what I can't understand is why when I type `console.log(arr)` it shows in the console all the weekend day in the month but when I type `console.log(arr[1])` it shows in the console undefined. I made a mistake when i posted `arr2` means `arr`,I just edited that in the post

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can't access any variable's contents before it is populated. Simple as that. It is irrelevant whether it's by index or otherwise. See the answers to [weird array behaviour in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49838597/215552) as to why you see the data after the fact.

Comment: @HereticMonkey This answer a part of my question,I understand now why `console.log(arr)` works and `console.log(arr[index])` can't work,but I still not get how I can access to every element in the array before I call the function `rendeDay`

Comment: How would eat a slice of a pizza before it's delivered to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are calling `console.log` too early. `console.log(arr)` only works, because a reference to that array is logged, which is updated as soon as `renderDay` is run. Check MDN here: [console.log documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#parameters)

> Please be warned that if you log objects in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox what you get logged on the console is a reference to the object, which is not necessarily the 'value' of the object at the moment in time you call console.log(), but it is the value of the object at the moment you open the console.

Try logging `arr[0]` *after* you called `renderDay` somewhere in your code.

You can also try to replace `console.log(arr)` with `console.log(arr.toString())` to get the value `arr` has at the exact moment you log it - it should be empty when being called before `renderDay` is run.

Comment: that's really works,when I try logging `arr[0]` after i called `rendeDay`,is there a way to make the values in `arr` accessible by their index,I mean `arr[0] arr[1]` .... etc before I called renderDay,because I need to use them in other functions

Comment: The array will be empty because `renderDay` is responsible for populating the array with values.